# How can I find out an ADUser's password expiry date or days left until password expiry?

Tags: c#, .net, active-directory

I have a list of ADUsers and I want to check if any of the users' passwords are expiring soon, but I can't find any property to check.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

This should do the trick to find out the time remaining until the password expires for each user:

```
private static TimeSpan GetTimeRemainingUntilPasswordExpiration(string domain, string userName)
{
    using (var userEntry = new System.DirectoryServices.DirectoryEntry(string.Format("WinNT://{0}/{1},user", domain, userName)))
    {
        var maxPasswordAge = (int)userEntry.Properties.Cast<System.DirectoryServices.PropertyValueCollection>().First(p => p.PropertyName == "MaxPasswordAge").Value;
        var passwordAge = (int)userEntry.Properties.Cast<System.DirectoryServices.PropertyValueCollection>().First(p => p.PropertyName == "PasswordAge").Value;
        return TimeSpan.FromSeconds(maxPasswordAge) - TimeSpan.FromSeconds(passwordAge);
    }
}
```

Note: you will need to add a reference to `System.DirectoryServices`.

Comment: Make sure that factors in Fine Grained Password Policies if you're using them or might be using them. I don't *think* it does, but, I've not seen the WinNT provider used here.

Comment: Is this a correct solution if domain policy is overriden by group policy?

Comment: If Users with Password Never Expires ?