# In Directory entry "maxPwdAge" throws the time limit for this request was exceeded

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, active-directory, directoryservices, directoryentry

I am writing a function to get the user expiration date in C# using ldap. I am currently refering the following link information to get the maxPwdAge from the Properties.

[Active Directory user password expiration date .NET/OU Group Policy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3764327/active-directory-user-password-expiration-date-net-ou-group-policy)

Problem with my code is that

```
var maxPwdAge = results[0].Properties["maxPwdAge"][0]; // Getting Error here
maxDays = (long)maxPwdAge / -864000000000;
```

in this line, I am getting Error as follows

> The time limit for this request was exceeded or 
>   "Function evaluation disabled because a previous function evaluation timed out. You must continue execution to reenable function evaluation."

I tried IADsLargeInteger also to get the value, but I am getting the same error for the both cases

```
object obj = entry.Properties["maxPwdAge"];// Getting Error here
ActiveDs.IADsLargeInteger largeIntADSI;
largeIntADSI = (ActiveDs.IADsLargeInteger)obj;
```

But after nearly 30 secs, I am getting 240 days, the expected result from my code.It is very  problematic issue.

Comment: Application is not responding or just hung for 30 secs in the var maxPwdAge = results[0].Properties["maxPwdAge"][0]; I couldn't find the root case for this problem.

Comment: Solved issue as follows  ActiveDs.IADsUser native = (ActiveDs.IADsUser)entry.NativeObject;
        DateTime passwordExpirationDate = native.PasswordExpirationDate;
        TimeSpan dayLeft = passwordExpirationDate.Date.Subtract(DateTime.Today);
        daysLeft = dayLeft.Days;