# Active directory password expiration

Tags: c#, active-directory

Is there a way to read proper password age if group policy overrides domain password age policy?
Thank you for your time.

Comment: Please see this link

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3764327/active-directory-user-password-expiration-date-net-ou-group-policy

Comment: @Saadkhatri Thank you, but this doesn't help me. Password age is linked to OU by Group Policy and I cannot see specified maxPwdAge at OU properties.