# How to set password expiry date of Active Directory using C#

Tags: c#, active-directory

Can any one help me with setting the password expiry date in AD using C#.

I have come across some articles in msdn and stack overflow which show how to set the password expiry dates. But I have noticed that these methods or snippets are valid till Server 2003.

Referred Links:

[Active Directory user password expiration date .NET/OU Group Policy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3764327/active-directory-user-password-expiration-date-net-ou-group-policy)

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/323750

I am having server 2008.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot set the password expiry for a given user if that's what you're trying to do.